# Change selected DataGridView row given an entity

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with DataSource set to a BindingSource control, that is bound to an ObservableList of entities.

I use this grid as a read only grid, for searching purposes.
When an item is selected, another BindingSource is updated with the current selected item.
No issues until here.

The issue is when creating a new item and I want to select the new item in the DataGrid, as after saving user is supposed to be able edit some data of the just created record.

How can I do that?
I can only provide the entity itself or the ID, but I can't figure out how to do that.
I'm not quite used working with Windows Forms, so I'm sure I'm missing some trivial solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some research and inspecting the "row" object, I've found this solution that perfectly meet my needs.

If anyone find any flaw with this approach, please let me know.

Once the new item is saved, I get the entity updated with the new primary key, then I call the following function:

```
private void SelectDataGridItem(Model.MyEntityType selectedItem)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MyDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        var boundItem = (Model.MyEntityType) row.DataBoundItem;
        if (boundItem.Id == selectedItem.Id)
        {
            row.Selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the `SelectedItem` property of the grid to a property where you can set what entity you wish to be selected. Not sure but you might need to trigger a refresh on the grid because it might not automatically refresh it's View.

Comment: DataGridView doesn't have a SelectedItem property. The only property I could use is dataGridView.Rows[0].Selected = true; , but this would mean that I have to loop through all rows, find the ID of the record and then select the matching row: I was hoping to find a better way.

Comment: SelectedRows only returns selected rows. As far as I can see is read-only. Even if I could write this property, it wouldn't be much different than looping through all rows.